# Injecting a dependency through a method parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I did all the bindings already. My problem now is getting the final binding to work on a static method property.

For eg:

```
Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
Bind<IUserRepository>().To<SqlServerUserRepository>().InRequestScope();

Bind<IDatabaseInitializer<EconoDb>>().To<DatabaseInitializer>();
//Problem here. How do I inject the user service here?
DbDatabase.SetInitializer(/*IDatabaseInitializer goes here */);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DatabaseInitializer` accepts the `IUserService` constructor parameter, you can use Ninject to resolve the instance:

```
var initializer = kernel.Get<IDatabaseInitializer<EconoDb>>()
DbDatabase.SetInitializer(initializer);
```

Entity Framework doesn't have any out of the box support for DI through an IoC/SL (as far as I am aware) which means you'll have to handle passing that value to the `DbDatabase.SetInitializer` call yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Hy
You can use OnActivation.

```
Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
Bind<IUserRepository>().To<SqlServerUserRepository>().InRequestScope();

Bind<IDatabaseInitializer<EconoDb>>().To<DatabaseInitializer>()
.OnActivation(initializer => DbDatabase.SetInitializer(initializer));
```

or the short version

```
Bind<IDatabaseInitializer<EconoDb>>().To<DatabaseInitializer>()
.OnActivation(DbDatabase.SetInitializer);
```